# Reset Local Administrator Password remotely

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, password

Back in the Windows 2000 I remember being able to reset and change the local administrator password on remote workstations with the following command from [MS KB 272530](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272530):

```
The following .bat file will change the local administrator password to newpass 
on the \\pc1, \\pc2, and \\pc3 computers: 

cusrmgr.exe -u Administrator -m \\pc1 -P newpass
cusrmgr.exe -u Administrator -m \\pc2 -P newpass
cusrmgr.exe -u Administrator -m \\pc3 -P newpass
```

However, this command does not seem to work in Windows 2003 or 2008.

Is there a new method that will allow me to change the local administrator password on my remote workstations similar to the cusrmgr command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer:

PsPasswrd.exe in the PsTools download.

Works great :-)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897543.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions have been discussed in [Windows Server 2003 Local Account Maintenance](https://serverfault.com/questions/31058/).