# Adding a user to the local Administrator group using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I would like to use PowerShell to add a specific user to the local administrator group on a machine.  I would be running the PowerShell script in the context of a user that has Administration rights on the local machine.

Comment: See also [Windows Local Account and Group Maintenance][1].


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/31058/windows-local-account-and-group-maintenance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Advanced Function That I use to add a users to the local Administrator group using Powershell on several computers.

Usage: Get-Content C:\Computers.txt | Set-LocalAdminGroupMembership -Account 'YourAccount'

---

```
Function Global:Set-LocalAdminGroupMembership
{


    <#
    .Synopsis

    .Description

    .Parameter $ComputerName,

    .Example
     PS> Set-LocalAdminGroupMembership -ComputerName $ComputerName -Account 'YourAccount'

    .Link
     about_functions
     about_functions_advanced
     about_functions_advanced_methods
     about_functions_advanced_parameters

    .Notes
     NAME:      Set-LocalAdminGroupMembership
     AUTHOR:    Innotask.com\dmiller
     LASTEDIT:  2/4/2010 2:30:05 PM
     #Requires -Version 2.0
    #>



    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $ComputerName = '.',
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
    $Account
    )


    Process
    {  

        if($ComputerName -eq '.'){$ComputerName = (get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Name}    
        $ComputerName = $ComputerName.ToUpper()


        $Domain = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN

        if($Domain){
            $adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/administrators,group"
            $adsi.add("WinNT://$Domain/$Account,group")
            }else{
            Write-Host "Not connected to a domain." -foregroundcolor "red"
            }


    }# Process


}# Set-LocalAdminGroupMembership
```

Answer (score 31):

On Server 2016 and Windows 10 Version 1607 and later you can use the new PowerShell local user cmdlets:

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member username
```

This was added in Windows Management Framework (WMF) 5.1.

The `Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts` module works fine on 2012 R2 if you just copy the files into a `$env:PsModulePath` location.

Comment: Be careful, the group "Administrators" might be called different depending on your locale, on a German system it is "Administratoren".

Comment: You can also add an AD group this way, eg:

Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member "CONTOSO\Domain Admins"

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple 2 line script that performs this function

```
$group = [ADSI]("WinNT://"+$env:COMPUTERNAME+"/administrators,group")
$group.add("WinNT://$env:USERDOMAIN/usernameiwantoadd,user")
```

For more information see [Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Use Windows PowerShell to Add a Domain User to a Local Group?](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/03/11/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-add-a-domain-user-to-a-local-group.aspx)

So there are a couple of notes.  In the first line I used string concatenation, I didn't have to (see the next line) but I like to because it helps accentuate the variables I am using.  Second, these lines will add a domain user, if you wanted to add a local user just remove `$env:USERDOMAIN/`

Comment: I would like to run this script on workstations in such a way that the person running the script can type in a username.  Hence the Read-Host

Comment: so in that case make the first line $userInput = Read-Host "Enter username to add to the local admin group" then use $userinput where is says usernameiwantoadd

Answer (score 3):

Simple Step to add a domain user to the Administrators group:

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member $env:USERDOMAIN\<username>
```

Note:
Make sure you run PowerShell "As Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this. This needs to be run in Administrator context:

```
$domain=""
$computername= "$env:computername"
$group=$computer.psbase.children.find("administrators")

function AddToGroup($number)
{
     $group.add("WinNT://"+$domain+"/"+$number )
}

#Add these domain users/groups to the local administrator group
 AddToGroup ""
 AddToGroup ""

#Add these domain computer accounts to the local administrator group. 
#Computer accounts always end with $.
AddToGroup "$"
```

More info on my [website](http://www.danielclasson.com/powershell-script-to-add-domain-computers-groups-or-user-accounts-to-the-local-administrator-group/).

Answer (score 0):

> Adding account that already exists in the target security group raises and error so you need to check if account is already added, however my requirement was to be backward compatible down to PowerShell **v2.0**

Below is the snippet I use to add a user to the local administrators group that works on older versions of PowerShell for Windows Servers prior 2016. The code example adds a service account used for custom IIS AppPool identity to the local Administrators group.

```
$appPoolIdentity = "DOMAIN\svc-acc-name"
# check if user is already member of the local administrators group - using case insensitive string comparison
if(((invoke-command {net localgroup administrators}) -match ($appPoolIdentity -replace '\\','\\')).Count -eq 0){
    Write-Host "The app pool identity user '$appPoolIdentity' is not found in the local 'Administrators' group."
    # add user to the local administrators group
    $adminGroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/administrators,group")
    $adminGroup.Add("WinNT://$appPoolIdentity,user")
    Write-Warning "Added '$appPoolIdentity' to the local 'Administrators' group."
}else{
    Write-Host "The app pool identity user '$appPoolIdentity' is already member of local 'Administrators' group."
}
```

Credit for using `net localgroup administrators` in the if statement above goes to [this blog post](https://powershell.org/2013/04/get-local-admin-group-members-in-a-new-old-way-3/).